# What does Thoreau mean by "horizontal body" in this paragraph from "The Last Days of John Brown"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

In [*The Last Days of John Brown*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/70123/pg70123-images.html#Page_278), Thoreau writes:

> “He nothing common did or mean Upon that memorable scene, Nor called the gods with vulgar spite, To vindicate his helpless right; But bowed his comely head Down as upon a bed.” What a transit was that of his **horizontal** body alone, but just cut down from the gallows-tree! We read, that at such a time it passed through Philadelphia, and by Saturday night had reached New York. Thus, like a meteor it shot through the Union from the Southern regions toward the North! No such freight had the cars borne since they carried him Southward alive.

I can understand that one could describe the transport of a body as horizontal, e.g. such that is carried out by train over the surface of the earth. What is meant here be the body itself being *[horizontal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horizontal)*?

Comment: I think you got the point. Anything else is a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: What's there to think about? John Brown's body was ***just cut down from the gallows-tree*** (where it was hanging ***vertically***). Once it's cut down, whether it initially lies above ground somewhere, or later [a-mouldering in the grave](https://www.famous-trials.com/johnbrown/622-brownbody), it will obviously be horizontally oriented. Egyptian mummies excepted, humans don't normally store corpses upright!

Comment: The part in quotation marks, incidentally, is Andrew Marvell writing about the execution of King Charles I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of *horizontal* is merely an emphatic, stressing to the reader the deadness of the man, the corpse-like attitude.

Most of us, when not sleeping or lounging, stand vertical; this is a sign of life, of our defiance of gravity. Corpses are usually arranged horizontal. A horizontal person may be sleeping or, in this case, dead.

Comment: Possibly also contrasting with a soul or spirit which would not be horizontal.

Comment: @StuartF Interesting thought. Yes, I suppose soul and spirit are implicitly three-dimensional. Not that we have any empirical evidence for that, but it seems to be how they are universally imagined.